# Wordpress render different header on mobile and desktop

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to render different Headers on mobile and desktop version in Wordpress.
For some odd reason the way the header is displayed is different.
Sometimes my desktop version has either the desktop header or the mobile header and then the mobile version also has one or the other.
How can that happen?
This is my code from the header.php

```
<?php if ( wp_is_mobile() ) : ?>
    <div class="vc_row gap-80 mobil">
        <div class="vc_col-xs-2 vc_col-sm-12 text-left">
            <div class="navigation">
                <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
                <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
                <nav id="nav" role="navigation">
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'Mainnavi' ) ); ?>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="vc_col-xs-8 vc_col-sm-12 text-center" style="padding-left: 0;">
            <?php if (get_field('logo','options')): ?>
                <a id="logo" style="height: <?php the_field('logo_grosse', 'options'); ?>px;" href="<?= get_home_url(); ?>" title="<?php the_field('logo_seo_alt_title' , 'options'); ?>">
                    <img alt="<?php the_field('logo_seo_alt_title' , 'options'); ?>"  style="height: <?php the_field('logo_grosse', 'options'); ?>px;" src="<?php the_field('logo','options'); ?>" />
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php else : ?>
    <div class="vc_row gap-80 desktop">
        <div class="vc_col-xs-3 vc_col-sm-3 vc_col-md-2 vc_col-lg-2 vc_col-xl-2 text-left" style="padding-left: 0;">
            <?php if (get_field('logo','options')): ?>
                <a id="logo" style="height: <?php the_field('logo_grosse', 'options'); ?>px;" href="<?= get_home_url(); ?>" title="<?php the_field('logo_seo_alt_title' , 'options'); ?>">
                    <img alt="<?php the_field('logo_seo_alt_title' , 'options'); ?>"  style="height: <?php the_field('logo_grosse', 'options'); ?>px;" src="<?php the_field('logo','options'); ?>" />
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="vc_col-xs-2 vc_col-sm-6 vc_col-md-7 vc_col-lg-8 vc_col-xl-9 text-center">
            <div class="navigation">
                <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
                <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
                <nav id="nav" role="navigation">
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'MainnaviDesktop' ) ); ?>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-right my-profile-container">
            <a class="my-profile" href="/profil/anmelden" title="Mein Konto">Mein Konto</a>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Maybe a CSS rule is in the way? Tried to disable all CSS and see if "wp_is_mobile()" works correct? "wp_is_mobile()" checks if it's a smartphone or tablet, some themes CSS code check this by screen width instead of HTTP_USER_AGENT, maybe this overlaps somehow.

Comment: I thought of that aswell, but sometimes i have the correct view and sometimes not.
It seems to change like every x hours (didn't keep track of the time)

Comment: Are you using any page caching?

Comment: Yes W3 Total Cache

Comment: W3 Total Cache could be a problem. Try the plugin "Mobble". Btw. "wp_is_mobile()" is not made for frontend I have heard, it's more for backend.

Comment: Both headers have different html structures.
How would i approach the problem, when iam not allowed to use wp_is_mobile()?

Comment: Please don't take this as a negative criticism, but targeting browsers by user agent is usually considered a bad practice, because inevitably edge cases will continuously creep up on you, and maintaining the "mobile database" is a burden unto itself. Instead, could you just make this responsive, and either let a single header respond naturally based on viewports, or continue to use two headers, but show/hide them at certain viewports?

Comment: Also, because `wp_is_mobile` is a server-side function, caching is generally out the door unless the cache is specifically built to support it. W3 Total Cache apparently has [something along these lines](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_is_mobile-is-not-working-when-enabled-page-enhanced-mode/), although it appears you need to manually add user agents.

Comment: Yes i can do generate both and just use display: none and block, that will work.
Ive heared that this approach is also not best practise due to rendering more content than needed.
Also i didnt take his comment negative i like criticism, since i can learn from that.
I was just curious due to rendering both is not best practise and using wp_is_mobile was like the only other thing i was able to find and was also called not best practise.

Comment: In an ideal world, I would try to have just a single block, and change the aspect of that block depending on how the viewport responds. When it comes to nav specifically, however, it is not uncommon to have two primary nav elements, one for larger (desktop) viewports and one for smaller (mobile) viewports. It is common, however, to have the mobile nav position `fixed`, so it often doesn't really need to be wrapped with anything specific. Yes, there's extra DOM that isn't rendered, but it is almost always negligible, and you can use caching again, so it is a win.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, that helps a lot.
I guess ill just follow your instruction